# Downsides of Storing Hundreds of Values in iOS using KeyChain

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, keychain

I'm looking to develop a game in Swift with the following potential requirements:

1. It can be played offline
2. It offers the ability to save and reload from other devices
3. Boolean data values can be accessed by the game to determine whether the player has unlocked the levels in the game, as well as what they purchased (how much gold they have, items unlocked, etc).
4. The data cannot be tampered with (I wouldn't want someone to give themselves gold or unlock strong weapons without rightfully purchasing them)

I believe KeyChain is a good approach for this for the following reasons:

1. I can store data as key/value pairs and access them offline (great for my true/false values for what levels/items are unlocked)
2. The entire collection of data can be exported as a name/value pair, thus I can send the entire dictionary (in just a few lines of code) to the user's account using CloudKit/GameCenter, and then have it synchronize to other user devices (by importing that data).
3. It offers very robust security

It feels weird for me to use KeyChain as a poor man's database but for the above reasons I listed I think it could work.

The problem is I could see the name/value pairs being somewhere in the 200-300 range. Would you say storing this many values in KeyChain is a bad decision? It doesn't seem particularly slow (yet).

An alternative to me is to use a database, however many of these values are simply true/false (what levels are unlocked, sword-1 unlocked, armor-3 unlocked, total gold acquired, etc). I suppose the game could grow where it suddenly becomes too robust to manage all of this using KeyChain (and instead I encrypt the database using SQLCipher) but I wanted to ask the community's opinion on storing this many values in KeyChain.

Thanks!

Comment: So why don't you use KVS or CloudKit? Are you really concerned about hacked devices? Do you really need to use 300 separate key/values if the values are just bools? Couldn't you at least encode your state as a single KV item (300 bools would be just ~38 bytes)?

Comment: Sorry what is KVS? Key values? I am using those but I want the game to be playable offline so I can't keep fetching from CloudKit every minute. Are you saying use keychain to store my key values? Thanks!

Comment: KVS is https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html. *What* are you using? Defaults? Why would you 'fetch from CloudKit every minute', that statement doesn't seem to make sense. No I'm not saying that you should use the keychain, it sounds like a bad idea. But if you really want to go that route, I would use a single keychain key.

Comment: So what do I use to persist locally for my offline situation? Does KVS work local? Seems like it uses the web. Thanks! Btw I'm using a single keychain now yes.

Comment: If you just need to store 300 flags, I would store that in a 40 byte file locally. Even defaults should be fine for such a large amount of data. How would KVS work locally? You want 'ability to save and reload from other devices'. Sure, you could use Bluetooth etc, but using iCloud sounds like the easiest way to share data between devices, whether KVS or CloudKit. Also: You don't answer questions, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Hey thanks looks like we're on the same page re CloudKit - seems like a modern approach and resembles what you're saying in regards to sending over the Key-Value pairs. I think my question specifically lies in whether to do this with an encrypted local file, or storing everything in keychain directly (and what the advantages or disadvantages are or why it's a bad idea as you suggested). Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just store your info in a plist, csv or database or any other kind of file in the documents directory and encrypt.  Store the key in the keychain and use they key to decrypt the file.  There are plenty of [cryptography pods](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) that will do this part for you so you don't have to deal with the joys of C interop with common crypto.

Comment: ok that sounds good. Is there any inheritance disadvantage/advantage of doing this over keychain for everything itself? If I need to make frequent read/writes, for example, was just wondering if the process of decrypting/encrypting/reading/writing to the file every time is better/worse than keychain directly? Thanks!

Comment: From what you described the file is small so it shouldn't take that long.  I would read the file in in ApplicationDidFinishLaunchin and write in ApplicationWillTerminate.  Otherwise use the in memory copy of the file when running.